# Twitter-Bootstrap 3 Collapsed Navbar overlaps header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, header, navbar

So I have a navbar that is fixed but becomes sticky when the user scrolls through the webpage. My problem is that whenever I resize my browser the navbar overlaps my subheader (the one with the "The Official Student Publication ..".

Webshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIxqo.png

HTML CODE For Index

```js
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
      }
});
```

```css
/* bootstrap 3 helpers */

.navbar-form input, .form-inline input {
 width:auto;
 position: absolute;
}

header {
 height:160px;
    
}

#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}







/* Create a medium height at 40px */
.navbar-md {min-height:40px}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand,
.navbar-md .navbar-nav>li>a {padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand {height: 40px}  
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle {margin: 6px 12px 6px 0px; padding: 6px 7px 6px 7px;}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {width: 19px;}




.container#slider {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container#headerC {
 padding:15px;
}

/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.navbar-header {
background-image:url("bootstraplogo.png", "bootstraplogoslice1.png")
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-position:center;

}




@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 991px) {
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.navbar-header {
    background-size: auto auto;
}
.navbar-header {
    height: 45px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.navbar-header {
background-size: auto 50px, 1px 50px;
}



.navbar-md#header {
height:50px;
}
}

/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.container-header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

p#headerP {

 display: inherit;

        padding: 30px 0 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
        font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 5em;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: normal;
        color: #8F1925;
}

p#subheader {
display: inherit;
        margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
        padding: 0 0 40px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: #E72635;

}





body {
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #FEFDFD;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
 padding-top: 10px;
 
}

header {
 height: 200px;

}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #000;
}

hr {
    max-width: 400px;
    border-color: #999999;
}

.brand,
.address-bar {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
 padding: 10px;
}



.navbar-nav {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.img-full {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.brand-before,
.brand-name {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.brand-before {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.brand-name {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.tagline-divider {
    margin: 15px auto 3px;
    max-width: 250px;
    border-color: #999999;
}

.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.intro-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.img-border {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    border: #999999 solid 1px;
}

.img-left {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}

footer {
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .brand {
        display: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 30px 0 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
        font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 5em;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: normal;
        color: #8F1925;
    }

    .top-divider {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .img-left {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

    .address-bar {
        display: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 40px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: #E72635;
    }

    .navbar {
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    .navbar-header {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar {
        min-height: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default {
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    }

    .nav>li>a {
        padding: 35px;
    }

    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        line-height: normal;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        display: table;
        float: left;
        table-layout: fixed;
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    .box:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="headerC">
<div class="text-center">
<header class="masthead">
<p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
<p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>

</header>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Navigation -->



                  

<div id="nav">
     
<div class=" navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-md">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-md">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Articles <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Article</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Editorial Cartoon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Uncensored</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Magazine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tejido</a></li>
            </ul>
          <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
    
    
    <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">The Staff<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Editorial Board</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          <li><a href="#">WMSU Portal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
   
    </ul>
   
  
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the height given for header

```
header {
  height: 200px;
}

header {
  height: 160px;
}
```

because of the `height` the `nav` was coming on overlapping on the `header`

```js
$('#nav').affix({
  offset: {
    top: $('header').height()
  }
});
```

```css
/* bootstrap 3 helpers */

.navbar-form input,
.form-inline input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Create a medium height at 40px */

.navbar-md {
  min-height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand,
.navbar-md .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand {
  height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 6px 12px 6px 0px;
  padding: 6px 7px 6px 7px;
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 19px;
}
.container#slider {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container#headerC {
  padding: 15px;
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.navbar-header {
  background-image: url("bootstraplogo.png", "bootstraplogoslice1.png") background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto auto;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    height: 45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto 50px, 1px 50px;
  }
  .navbar-md#header {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.container-header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
p#headerP {
  display: inherit;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #8F1925;
}
p#subheader {
  display: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #E72635;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FEFDFD;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #000;
}
hr {
  max-width: 400px;
  border-color: #999999;
}
.brand,
.address-bar {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.img-full {
  min-width: 100%;
}
.brand-before,
.brand-name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.brand-before {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.brand-name {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
}
.tagline-divider {
  margin: 15px auto 3px;
  max-width: 250px;
  border-color: #999999;
}
.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.intro-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.img-border {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  border: #999999 solid 1px;
}
.img-left {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
footer {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .brand {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
    font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #8F1925;
  }
  .top-divider {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .img-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .address-bar {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #E72635;
  }
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar {
    min-height: 0;
  }
  .navbar-default {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    padding: 35px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: normal;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .box:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" id="headerC">
  <div class="text-center">
    <header class="masthead">
      <p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
      <p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>

    </header>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Navigation -->





<div id="nav">

  <div class=" navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-md">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-md">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Articles <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Article</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Comics</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Editorial Cartoon</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Uncensored</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Magazine</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Tejido</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
          </li>


          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">The Staff<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Editorial Board</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#">WMSU Portal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
            </li>

      </ul>


      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```